# Handling errors core async, when it's used in async/await style

Tags: clojure, core.async

I am using core async. In the scenario I care for, I am using it similar to how one would use async / await (all processes are kicked off by a caller, and eventually return)

#### Problem: Propagating errors

By default, go-blocks fail silently when there are errors

```
(defn go-uh-oh
  []
  (go
    (throw (Exception. "uh-oh"))))

(<!! (go
      (let [a-chan (go-uh-oh item-one)
            b-chan (go-uh-oh item-two)]
       [(<! a-chan) (<! b-chan)]))
```

The top-level take would simply return [nil nil]. Instead, it would be great if we propagated errors and threw.

### Potential Solution: go-try

To solve this, it looks like the idiomatic solution is to introduce the `go-try` and `<?` macro. The `go-try` macro wraps the body of a go block in a try-catch, and returns the error if it exists. `<?` then takes from these kind of go-blocks. If the item is an error, it re-throws. This way errors propagate. Here's an example implementation: https://github.com/alexanderkiel/async-error

So if we wrote the above like so, errors propagate:

```
(defn go-uh-oh
  [arg]
  (go-try
   (throw (Exception. "uh-oh"))))

(<??
 (go-try (let [a-chan (go-uh-oh 1)
               b-chan (go-uh-oh 2)]
           [(<? a-chan) (<? b-chan)])))
```

Errors would propagate and we would get the result.

### Buut, problem with go-try

But there's a problem with using `go-try` and `<?`. Now, if I have some intermediate functions to compose some `go-try` blocks, errors would get lost again. For example:

```
(<?? (a/into [] (a/merge [(uh-oh-go-try) (uh-oh-go-try)])))
```

Here, `<??` would see a vector of `[Error, Error]`, and would not propagate anything up.

I *could* change the way `<??` is implemented, and have it consider arrays of errors too. But I wonder if there is a better way. How do you handle error propagation in this case?

Comment: What the heck is `go-try`? I find no evidence of it in core.async's documentation or implementation.

Comment: I guess `go-try` is from [async-error](https://github.com/alexanderkiel/async-error).

Comment: can i please ask you, what are you trying to achieve?
what's the desired behaviour?
don't know.. maybe this will help https://blog.jakubholy.net/2019/core-async-error-handling/

Comment: seems like `pipeline` with error handler is good enough.. idk )

Comment: Hey team, sorry for the late response. I went ahead and added more context. Let me know if you have any ideas!